# Codesys Automatic xExecute NBS.TCP_write

Tags: tcp, codesys

I've recently started experimenting with CODESYS for a project and am fairly new to it. I'm currently working with Function Block Diagrams (FBD) to set up TCP communication between a server and a client, where the client is implemented as a Python script. Once the communication is established, my connection status changes to True, which is the expected behavior.

My challenge arises with the TCP write module, which requires the xEnable_write flag to toggle between True and False. If xEnable_write remains True, the module only performs a single write operation. To address this, I introduced a falling edge trigger (F_TRIG), expecting it to help in toggling xEnable_write and it does, However, I've encountered an issue where in the beginning after connxion established I need to manually set xEnable_write to True for the system to work as intended. I'm looking for a way to automate this process so that xEnable_write becomes True automatically upon establishing a connection .

Initially, I tried setting xEnable_write to True from the start, but this approach didn't work well since it left the flag permanently True, preventing further toggling. I also experimented with using a TON timer, but I faced similar issues.

I am seeking a solution that automatically toggles xEnable_write between True and False after a connection is established, ensuring continuous write operations without manual intervention. Any advice or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with the TCP stack in CODESYS, so I'll make some assumptions from your explanation:

- `TCP_Connection.xActive` indicates that `TCP_Write` can be executed (if not busy).
- `TCP_Write.xDone` indicates that `TCP_Write` is free and can be executed.
- `TCP_Write` executes when it detects a rising edge on `xExecute`.

If the above is true, and your goal is to repeatedly execute `TCP_Write`, then we need 2 things:

1. Start executing `TCP_Write` when the connection is ready.
2. Execute `TCP_Write` as soon as the last write finishes.

By adding `F_TRIG` to `xDone`, you correctly dealt with the second point, since when a write finishes and `xDone` output beccomes true, `F_TRIG` detects the falling edge (you could probably also use `R_TRIG` here) and pulses `xExecute`, which starts another write.

The problem is the first point. `xDone` is only set (and then reset on the next cycle) when an operation is already executed, so you need to execute the first operation. Setting `xExecute` to TRUE from the start is incorrect, since the connection hasn't been established yet. For that, you need to use the `TCP_Connection.xActive` output, in other words, as soon as `xActive` becomes TRUE, you can execute the first write (set `xExecute` to TRUE for 1 cycle).

You may think that adding a rising edge (`R_TRIG`) to `xActive` would solve it, but the problem with having 2 triggers write to the same variable is that they would overwrite each other. To solve this, one way would be to add a `R_TRIG` to the `xActive` output and write the result into a temporary variablem for example `xEcecute1`, and have the `F_TRIG` after `xDone` write the result into another variable, for example `xExecute2`. Now we can execute a write when either `xExecute1` or `xExecute2` is set to true, in other words, when either the connection is first established, or a previous write is done (`TCP_Write.xExecute := xExecute1 OR_ELSE xExecute2`).

If you want to go one step further, I'd suggest looking at `xBusy`, `xError` and `eError` in the documentation, and deciding whether you should pause the toggling of `xExecute` in some conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your response ,the solution was just adding (TCP_Connection_0.xActive AND NOT TCP_Write_0.Xdone ) to xExcute

Comment: Then it looks like if `xDone` is FALSE, `TCP_Write` ignores `xExecute`, since you are telling it to execute a new write, while a write is still in progress. Once a write finishes, `xDone` becomes TRUE which makes `xExecute` become false, and on next cycle `xDone` becomes false, which makes `xExecute` become TRUE, which is detected as a rising edge and starts a new write. On first boot `xDone` is FALSE, so once `xActive` becomes TRUE, `xExeute` also becomes TRUE ands starts the first write. A simple solution you found 